# How to convert number to string inside angular 2 component:

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

Inside the component i have

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


public errorMsg :number =10 ;

public doughnutChartOptions: any = {
 cutoutPercentage: 85,
  elements: {
    center: {
      text: this.errorMsg + ' Energy produced in the Energy',
      fontColor: '#fff',
      fontFamily: "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif",
      fontSize: 24,
      fontStyle: 'normal'
    }
  }
};
```

}

```
  text: this.errorMsg + ' some thing',
```

This is a property accepted string , so here i have to pass the number to string , How to do that in angular4,typescript 2.5

Comment: are you saying what you do gives you an error? if so, what is the error?

Comment: TypeScript has the same type coercion as JS, so numbers are automatically converted to strings when used in a string context.

Comment: I have closed this topic , got a clear idea from Gunter and Saurabh, thanks for the valuable comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pls try

```
text:  `${this.errorMsg} Energy produced in the Energy`,
```

NB: Use  ``  (back-ticks)   ,   instead of `''` (apostrophe), to get your value.

Answer (score 20):

Integer to string is as simple as calling `.toString();`

As @GünterZöchbauer said **TypeScript has the same type coercion as JS, so numbers are automatically converted to strings when used in a string context**

So no problem will occur same as Javascript, you can use number as string.

If you want you can do it like this so :

```js
const num = 3;//number
const stringForm = num.toString();
console.log(stringForm);
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use  ''+your number

```
let num:number=3;
let numTxt:string=''+number;
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be converted into the string automatically,
for an example

```
class myClass{
    private myNum: number = 10;
    private myName: string = "Name Surname";
    
    onInit() {
        console.log(this.myName+this.myNum);    
    }
}
```

will be converted into these lines when transpiled

```
var myClass = /** @class */ (function () {
    function myClass() {
        this.myNum = 10;
        this.myName = "Name Surname";
    }
    myClass.prototype.onInit = function () {
        console.log(this.myName + this.myNum);
    };
    return myClass;
}());
```

that you can check in typescript website under play ground section,

#### [Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20myClass%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20myNum%3A%20number%20%3D%2010%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20myName%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22Name%20Surname%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20onInit()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.myName%2Bthis.myNum)%3B%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let num = 3;//number
let stringForm = num.toString();
console.log(stringForm);
```